# How to remove the title from yellowbrick ROCAUC

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, yaxis, yellowbrick

I am using yellowbrick to plot the AUCROC. I want to remove the title from the plot, to make it empty without the plot title.

```
model = classifier
visualizer = ROCAUC(model, encoder={0: 'class' , 1: 'class2'}
visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)        
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)       
visualizer.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You seem to be asking two questions here, please post each one separately so we can answer them individually.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. 

Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Comment: first you could check in documentation if it has option for this. Next you can check source code if you could create own function without title.

Comment: yellowbrick documentation [How can I change the title of a Yellowbrick plot?](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=title#how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-yellowbrick-plot) - and you could try with empty string `title=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yellowbrick documentation [How can I change the title of a Yellowbrick plot?](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=title#how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-yellowbrick-plot)

If I use single space in `title=" "` then I get plot without title.
It doesn't work with empty string `title=""`.

---

Minimal working example

```
from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier

# single space in title
visualizer = ROCAUC(RidgeClassifier(), title=" ")
visualizer.show()
```

[image]